# two functions interfering with each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

So my first stab at web development is proceeding *reasonably* well.
However... I want to have two separate drop down menus, but the JavaScript functions are interfering with each other... That is, if both functions are active at the same time, clicking on one drop down will cause the other drop down to react or stop working. It is probably something massively stupid, but I have little time left. here is the code:

```
//Control sliding menu on screens smaller than a specified breakpoint.
(function(menu_button, links, breakpoint) 
{
    "use strict";
    var menulink = document.getElementById(menu_button),
    menu = document.getElementById(links);

    menu.className = "start";
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        menu.className = "collapsed";
    }, 20);

    menuLink.onclick = function() 
    {
        if (menu.className === "displayed") 
        {
            menu.className = "collapsed";
        } 
        else 
        {
            menu.className = "displayed";
        }
        return false;
    };

    window.onresize = function() 
    {
        if (window.innerWidth < breakpoint) 
        {
            menu.className = "collapsed";
        }
    };  
})("menuLink", "navLinks", 700);
```

That was function No.1, here is No.2:

```
function dropFunction() 
{
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("drop");
}

window.onclick = function(e) 
{
    "use strict";
    if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) 
    {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdownContent");
        for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) 
        {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains("drop")) 
            {
                openDropdown.classList.remove("drop");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and HTML if at all usefull:

```
<nav>
    <p id="menuLink"><a href="#navLinks">MENU</a></p>
    <ul class="displayed" id="navLinks">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="dropdownContent" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#"><img class="externalLink" src="images/faceBook.png" style="width:20px"></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="externalLink" src="images/linkedIn.png" style="width:20px"></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="externalLink" src="images/soundCloud.png" style="width:20px"></a>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.nav
{
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 220px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-family: "verdana";
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li
{
    display: inline;
}

.nav a
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #E4E4E4;
}

.nav a:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #FFFFFF;
}

.nav a:active
{
    color: #5B4CA8;
}

li.drops
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdownContent 
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    minimum-width: 20px;
}

.dropdownContent a 
{
    color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.drop
{
    display: block;
}

#menuLink 
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#menuLink a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "helvetica";
    color: #E4E4E4;
}

#menuLink a:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #FFFFFF;
}

#menuLink a:active
{
   color: #5B4CA8;
}

#navLinks
{
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-out 0.5s;
    transition: all ease-out 0.5s;
}

#navLinks a
{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: "helvetica";
    color: #E4E4E4;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#navLinks a:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #FFFFFF;
}

#navLinks a:active
{
    color: #5B4CA8;
}

#navLinks.start
{
    display: none;
}

#navLinks.collapsed
{
    top: -12em;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: We need a stripped-down example. Anyway, how can "two functions be active at the same time"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the window.Onlcick event to specify behaviors for the dropdowns if the user is not clicking on something with class "drop". This event will fire if you click on any item in that window because events bubble up like that in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am not sure what to replace that with though... I guess I will experiment.

Comment: You may add event listeners to any element just like you have added the click event listner to the window element. You may use something like getElementsByClassName(). Or if you're not limited to plain JavaScript you could use Jquery.